# jquery file upload not working with jquery 3.x

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

My script works fine with jQuery 1.x and 2.x, but it doesn't work with jQuery 3.x

```
imageInput.fileupload();
var jqXHR = imageInput.fileupload('send', {
    files: files,
    formData: $.extend({csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken}, attachmentData),
    url: {{ id }}_settings.url.upload_attachment,
})
.success(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $.each(result.files, function (index, file) {
        console.log('success');
    });
})
.error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('error occurred.');
});
```

The FF browser complains that `success` and `error` function is NOT found.

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: imageInput.fileupload(...).success is not a function 
....
undefined
```

This is the error message. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Make sure you're not using jQuery-slim

Comment: @Phil Thank you for your prompt answer. I'm not sure if this version is jQuery-slim is or not.

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js

Comment: That one looks ok

Comment: I used NOT slim one, so I think I'll have to study with the answer by @adeneo. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuerys `success` and `error` were initially part of `$.ajax`, as in

```
$.ajax({
    success : function() {},
    error   : function() {}
})
```

But as `$.ajax` starter returning Deferreds, it changed to `done` and `fail`

```
$.ajax({}).done().fail()
```

This caused some confusion, so identical methods called `success` and `error` was added as well, so one could do

```
$.ajax({}).success().error()
```

The decision to remove `success` and `error` was made in the release of jQuery 3.x

https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-special-case-deferred-methods-removed-from-jquery-ajax

You can just swap in `done` and `fail` as direct replacements in your code for `success` and `error` as the Fileupload plugin uses jQuery's $.ajax under the hood.
jQuery's Deferreds are now Promise A+ compliant, so one could use `then` and `catch` as well

Comment: I just replaced function name, and it works fine. However, I'll have to make the code portable. Thank you.